# Force Python to forego native sqlite3 and use the (installed) latest sqlite3 version

Tags: python, sqlite

The error message I am trying to get rid of is:

> AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection'
>   object has no attribute
>   'enable_load_extension'

I have 'easy_install'-ed the latest sqlite3 version and python somehow know it is there since sqlite3.version_info produces 3.6.13. In this version the Connection should have the 'enable_load_extension' attribute.

What I think is going on is that python still uses the native sqlite3 module which I think is 2.4.1 since sqlite3.version (i.s.o. sqlite3.version_info) produces 2.4.1.

The question is how do I force python to use the new sqlite3 module for all sqlite3 calls?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`sqlite3` support in Python can be a bit confusing. The sqlite database adapter started out as a separate project, [pysqlite2](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite), but for Python 2.5 a version of it was incorporated into the Python standard library under the name [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).  The original adapter continues to be developed as that separate project while periodically the version in Python itself is updated to match it.  If you are trying to use a newer version of the adapter, it is usually installed as `pysqlite2` so as not to conflict with the version included in the standard library.  And, depending how it was built, it may link to a different version of the underlying [sqlite3 database library](http://www.sqlite.org/).  So make sure you are importing it properly:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version_info
(2, 4, 1)
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version_info
(3, 6, 11)

>>> from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version_info
(2, 5, 5)
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version_info
(3, 6, 18)
```

`version_info` is the version of the `sqlite3` (`pysqlite2` or built-in `sqlite3`) database adapter.
`sqlite_version_info` is the version of the underlying `sqlite3` database library.

Using `from ... import ... as sqlite3` is suggested so that the rest of your code does not need to change if you move from one version to the other.

Note, [`enable_load_extension`](https://pysqlite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.enable_load_extension) first appeared in `pysqlite2` 2.5.0.

**EDIT:** `enable_load_extension` is disabled by default when you build the adapter.  To enable it, you can build `pysqlite2` manually.  The following recipe assumes a `unix`-y system and the lastest version of `pysqlite2`, which as of this writing is 2.5.5.

First, if you installed the adapter originally via `easy_install`, uninstall it by first running:

```
$ sudo /path/to/easy_install -m pysqlite # or whatever package name you first used
```

There will be some output from that including lines like:

```
Removing pysqlite 2.5.5 from easy-install.pth file

Using /path/to/site-packages/pysqlite-2.5.5-py2.x-something.egg
```

Remove the egg using the file name listed (the name will vary depending on your platform and version and it may refer to a file or a directory):

```
$ sudo rm -r /path/to/site-packages/pysqlite-2.5.5-py2.x-something.egg
```

Now download and extract the `pysqlite-2.5.5` source tarball:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/build
$ cd /tmp/build
$ curl http://oss.itsystementwicklung.de/download/pysqlite/2.5/2.5.5/pysqlite-2.5.5.tar.gz | tar xz
$ cd pysqlite-2.5.5
```

Then edit the `setup.cfg` file to comment out the `SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION` directive:

```
$ ed setup.cfg <<EOF
> /SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION/s/define=/#define=/
> w
> q
> EOF
```

Since the version of `sqlite3` is so old (3.4.0), you should also build with the latest `sqlite3` library.  This is made easy in the `pysqlite2` setup.py script:

```
$ /path/to/python2.x setup.py build_static
```

This will automatically download the latest [sqlite3 amalgamation source](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and build the adapter along with an up-to-date statically-linked version of `sqlite3`.  This step may take a long while to finish.

**UPDATE (2015/07/21)**: According to the latest [pysqlite 2.6.3 commit](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/commit/2d7360cc94c652b8ebfd063940beeaa7451db9dd) you **have to** download sqlite source code by yourself and put them in pysqlite root folder.

Now, install the adapter:

```
$ sudo /path/to/python2.x setup.py install
```

and run the tests:

```
$ cd     # somewhere out of the build directory
$ /path/to/python2.x
>>> from pysqlite2 import test
>>> test.test()
```

and, if they pass, you should be all set.

As a bonus, if the reason you want load extension support is to use `sqlite3`'s full text search extension, `FTS3`, you should find that it was included as part of the static library and no further work is necessary:

```
>>> from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
>>> con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
>>> con.execute("create virtual table recipe using fts3(name, ingredients)")
<pysqlite2.dbapi2.Cursor object at 0xca5e0>
```

Comment: Dear Ned:

This surely has helped me a lot - thanks! Now my python script does seem to load the most recent version of the adapter after using the 'from ... import ... as sqlite3' construction, as I get 2.5.5 for version_info and 3.4.0 for sqlite_version. Yet, one line further I try to use 'enable_load_extension' and I now get:

AttributeError: 'pysqlite2.dbapi2.Connection' object has no attribute 'enable_load_extension'

By all the information you have given me this seems to be surprising, no? 

Thanks a lot for your help thus far - really appreciated!

--Albert

Comment: Darn!  I've expanded the answer to include how to build the adapter with load extension support enabled and with an up-to-date version of the sqlite3 library.

Comment: Ned, thanks for your quick reply. I have followed your instructions literally. My system now does have the latest sqlite3 version. However, if I type 'from pysqlite2 import test', I get the following error:

    from pysqlite2._sqlite import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pysqlite2/_sqlite.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pysqlite2/_sqlite.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

:(, sorry to bother you again with this. I feel I am very close now... Thanks a lot (!) for all your help thus far, Albert

Comment: It looks like you missed one important detail: the build command is now /usr/bin/python2.5 setup.py build_static . The symptoms you see are what you would get if you typed "build" instead of "build_static".  To rebuild: cd /tmp/build ; rm -r build ; /usr/bin/python2.5 setup.py build_static ; sudo ...

Comment: I have tried again based on your advice, but now I get the following error after running 'from pysqlite2 import test':

'ImportError: No module named _sqlite'

I do get a lot of warnings along the way when running the 'build_static' command. Ah, I wish I did not have to bother you again with this. Albert

Comment: Sorry, there was one other thing: you need to cd out of the build directory to be able to import pysqlite2 successfully.

Comment: I have done that (and tried it again just now). Still same issue. I feel that somehow it has something to do with using the standard python that ships with mac os x (which I always update). I plan to do a complete fresh install of the latest python version from source. Do you think this might be the issue? Best, Albert P.S.: Which timezone are you - you seem to be always online :-)? I am in New York.

Comment: From the messages you've reported, I assumed you were using OS X 10.5 and I've stepped through the recipe using the Apple-supplied python 2.5 on 10.5. There's no reason it shouldn't work for you. Installing from source is seldom necessary; if you need a newer version, use an OS X installer from python.org.  Just be careful you to know which python you are using: /usr/bin/python2.5 for the Apple one, generally /usr/local/bin/python2.x for a python.org one. ...

Comment: That said: one more idea. Perhaps you have a file permission issue. Try this command: sudo chmod 755 /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/pysqlite2/_sqlite.so It should not give any error message. Then try the test again.

Comment: IT WORKS - IT WORKS - IT WORKS !!! 

I am really happy with this Ted, thanks a lot! I did not install the latest python. And, I did not even execute the chmod command you suggested. Somehow the permissioning was done overnight. Happy surprise this morning. Again, thanks and this closes the issues. I am sure others will benefit from reading all your helpful advice here. Best, Albert

Comment: The day I reach my threshold reputation points I'll vote for you; I understood from trying just now that I do not have any such points yet as a newly arrived enthusiast. Albert

Comment: Yay!  I knew you could do it!  If the answer works for you, as a good StackOverflow citizen, you should mark the answer as "accepted". Then the responder gets points.

Comment: I have just done that, right? I have ticked the V so that it colors green (sorry did not know about it).

Comment: It worked for me! (Even though some steps failed and I had to do them manually) But only on Python2. Is there a way that it also updates the Python3 one?

Comment: This helped much. For others' reference, I got the compilation to work simply using a normal `python setup.py build`, and did not need to do the suggested `build_static`, which failed for me.

Comment: Sadly you are unable to enable_load_extension this way in Python3 since pysqlite2 is only for Python2.

In order to enable_load_extension, you have to recompile Python3 with the configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions flag.

It is really desirable that pip could handle this kind of customizations in Python2 and Python3, something like: pip install pysqlite3 --configure-opts="--enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions"

Answer (score 14):

I have python 2.7 on a windows machine and the built-in sqlite3.sqlite_version was 3.6.x. By performing the following steps I was able to get it to use sqlite 3.7.9.

1. Download and unzip the pre-compiled binary DLL ("sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3070900.zip" on http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)
2. (probably should close all instances of python at this point just to be safe) Go to C:\Python27\DLLs and change filename of "sqlite3.dll" to "sqlite3.dll.old"
3. Copy the file "sqlite3.dll" to the folder C:\Python27\DLLs
4. Open python shell and import sqlite3
5. Verify sqlite3.sqlite_version shows up as '3.7.9'

Comment: Thanks Will. However I'm wondering if there is no risk of incompatibility between new sqlite3.dll and the python 2.7.? sqlite3 package code. I suppose sqlite3 package was tested against a particular sqlite3.dll and it's API may evolve in time. Maybe you were just lucky with these particular versions and test scenarios... Or is there a test suite?

Comment: Hi Dim, I didn't do any testing, so it is possible I just got lucky!

Comment: Seems to work for me also. I went from 3.6.21 to 3.8.8.2, which is 5 years of updates.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at your Python path and make sure that the sqlite you want is installed in an earlier directory than the built-in sqlite.

You can see the path with:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If you want to find out where a module is from, try:

```
print(sqlite3.__file__)
```

Comment: Dear Ned:

This is very useful - thanks a lot! I feel I am much closer now to completely solving the issue after your comment and the one posted by Ned Deily. 

--Albert

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the standard Python `sqlite3` module, you might be able to use the [apsw](https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw) module, a third-party SQLite module that more closely follows the SQLite API.  It includes support for loading extensions, as well as basically anything that is allowed in the SQLite C/C++ API.  It also tries as much as possible to keep up to date with any new changes in SQLite.