# Python sqlite3 version

Tags: python, sqlite

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.4.1'
```

Questions:

- Why is the version of the sqlite**3** module **'2.4.1'**
- Whats the reason behind bundling such an old sqlite with Python? The sqlite releaselog says **2002 Mar 13 (2.4.1)**.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
Python 2.5.1
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.3.2'
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.3.4'
```

version - pysqlite version
sqlite_version - sqlite version

Comment: Odd verisoning on the part of SQlite.

Comment: The pysqlite database adapter is a totally separate project from the underlying sqlite3 database project so the version numbers are not related.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545479/force-python-to-forego-native-sqlite3-and-use-the-installed-latest-sqlite3-vers/1546162 for an extended discussion.

Comment: One liner to print to CLI:


`python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.version); print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"`