# How can I make python 3.5.1 use a specific (preferably latest) version of the sqlite3 module instead of the standard one?

Tags: python, sqlite, debian, raspbian

I have a script that **has** to use Python 3.5.1 which I have installed. It also needs to use sqlite3 version 3.8.2 or higher. However, the module that seems to be installed has the version 3.7.13.

Could anybody please tell me how do I make it such that my script when run with python 3.5.1 will run such an sqlite3 version?

If it is of any importance I am using Raspbian.

Comment: @KobiK: not the module, the *C library*.

Comment: @KobiK: the Python module is part of the standard library, you don't install it with pip..

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545479/force-python-to-forego-native-sqlite3-and-use-the-installed-latest-sqlite3-ver) looks like it answers a similar problem.

Comment: It does not. pysqlite2 is not found in this version of python and when trying to install it by downloading the source code I get the message "pysqlite is not supported on Python 3. When using Python 3, use the sqlite3 module from the standard library."

Comment: you could check SQLite vision refer [to post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553160/python-sqlite3-version)

Comment: I know. That is how I found out my sqlite3 version that python 3.5 uses. I also know that from the fact that it does gives out an error at `WITHOUT ROWID` in my query and https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html claims that I need at least sqlite3 3.8.2. I also couldn't find a workaround to using `WITHOUT ROWID`