# Building python 2.6 w/ sqlite3 module if sqlite is installed in non-standard location

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to build python2.6 with support for the sqlite3 module.

I have successfully built and installed the sqlite-amalgamation to a non standard path:
./configure --prefix=/my/non/standard/install/path/sqlite/3.6.20/
make
make install

I would like the python2.6 build to use this path & build the sqlite3 module. I checked './configure --help' but did not see any type of "--with-sqlite-dir=path" option.

How can I let python's configure know where sqlite lives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than rebuilding `python`, the simplest way to get the most recent `sqlite3` is to install the [pysqlite](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite/) package which is the more up-to-date version of the standard library's `sqlite3` module.  It includes support for more recent `sqlite3` features and is upwards compatible.  More details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545479/force-python-to-forego-native-sqlite3-and-use-the-installed-latest-sqlite3-vers).

Comment: Hi Ned, thanks for your suggestion I downloaded pysqlite-2.5.5 and used "python setup.py build_static" followed by "python setup.py install" and in my script I am able to use "from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3" to get up and running on this machine. I am still a bit puzzled that I can't tell python's configure script where my sqlite install lives - this is still the optimal solution since I have scripts (and third party dependencies) that rely on  "import sqlite3".

Comment: The python autoconf and Makefile infrastructure is rather complex and non-standard in many respects, with cruft over many years and supporting many architectures and options.  Looking at the code in setup.py (and without any testing or knowing what platform you're building on), it looks like in most cases the easiest option would be to install the desired sqlite3 into /usr/local/{include,lib}.  If that's not feasible, adding the include and lib dirs to the configure step should work:  ./configure LDFLAGS='-L/path/to/lib' CPPFLAGS="-I/path/to/include' ...

Comment: Success! I previously tried setting LDFLAGS & CFLAGS in my in environment to get python to pick up the location - but I didn't try CPPFLAGS which was the key. Thanks for your help!