# Why can't I read IPhone SMS databases using Python 2.7?

Tags: iphone, python, sqlite

I think this must be a sqlite version problem, but I'm not sure how to diagnose it.  I'm using Python 2.7.1.

If I use the sqlite console, I can read my messages:

```
C:\>sqlite3 -version
3.7.10 2012-01-16 13:28:40 ebd01a8deffb5024a5d7494eef800d2366d97204
C:\>sqlite3 "c:\Users\wrightm\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\59aeac0d1993f5088fccb52978016c9fa9d5eae2\3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28" "select count(*) from message;"
5722
```

But, python 2.7 can't.  I assume the db version for IPhone sms backups is wrong, but how do I determine that version?

```
C:\>python -c "import sqlite3;print sqlite3.sqlite_version"
3.6.21
C:\>python -c "import sqlite3;sqlite3.connect(r'c:\Users\wrightm\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\59aeac0d1993f5088fccb52978016c9fa9d5eae2\3d0d7e5fb2ce28881330').execute('select count(*) from message;').fetchall()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: message
```

Comment: Btw - upgrading the version of sqlite.dll as suggested here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545479/force-python-to-forego-native-sqlite3-and-use-the-installed-latest-sqlite3-ver/1546162#1546162] doesn't help.  I still get no such table even after sqlite_version shows 3.7.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

path in the first version:

> c:\Users\wrightm\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\59aeac0d1993f5088fccb52978016c9fa9d5eae2\3d0d7e5fb2ce28881330**6e4d4636395e047a3d28**

path in the second version:

> c:\Users\wrightm\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\59aeac0d1993f5088fccb52978016c9fa9d5eae2\3d0d7e5fb2ce28881330

looks like you missed some characters in the second filename.

Comment: How embarrassing.  Thanks for the second set of eyes.  Not really stackoverflow appropriate, I guess.