# Updating the SQLite3 build on my python install

Tags: python, sqlite

noob programmer here, I'm trying to get the SQLite3 on my Python installation up-to-date (I currently have version 3.6.11, whereas I need at least version 3.6.19, as that is the first version that supports foreign keys). Here's my problem, though: I have no idea how to do this. I know next to nothing about the command line, and I don't really know what files to replace (if at all) in my python install. And before anyone asks, I'm already using the latest Pysql version – it's what's not up to date. Can anyone give me some pointers, or maybe a guide on how to update this?

I'm on Mac OSX 10.5.8, working with python 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the 'pip' command on the command line.

```
pip search sqlite
pip install pysqlite
```

Comment: make sure to install setuptools. but pip is the preferred method to do this in python. or try 'easy_install pip'

Answer (score 2):

I just came fresh from installing this both in Mavericks and Mountain Lion.

This [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545479/force-python-to-forego-native-sqlite3-and-use-the-installed-latest-sqlite3-ver/1546162#1546162) mentions using the build_static method, which they say retrieves that latest version of the sqlite amalgamation. For some reason it didn't work (ie it didn't seem to download it or use it)

What I ended up doing was

1. Downloaded pysqlite as a tarball
2. Downloaded latest sqlite source amalgamation
3. Unzipped pysqlite into its folder
4. Unzipped sqlite and *copied* that to the pysqlite folder
5. Opened setup.cfg and commented out all of the directives
6. In Terminal, went to the pysqlite folder, and then:

`$ python setup.py build_static install`

This compiled pysqlite using the libraries from the latest sqlite sources. And then in Python, I used it as:

`import pysqlite2.dbapi2 as sqlite3`

Comment: This solution worked for me. I did need to configure/make/make install inside of the pysqlite folder before the setup.py command would run successfully.

Comment: This help me too. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I recently installed python from source and used the following commands to install both SQLite from source and Python 2.7.13 from source.

for SQLite3 you can use the following commands
$SQLITE_INSTALL_LOCATION

```
$ curl -O http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3070603.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3070603.tar.gz
$ cd sqlite-autoconf-3070603
$ ./configure --prefix=$SQLITE_INSTALL_LOCATION --disable-static CFLAGS="-g"
$ make && make install
```

Then when I compiled my python I edited the setup.py in the root of the Python source

```
$ curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tgz
$ tar xvfz Python-2.7.13.tgz
```

Python-2.7.13/setup.py  -- add the path to your SQLite install here:
```

```
...
# We hunt for #define SQLITE_VERSION "n.n.n"
# We need to find >= sqlite version 3.0.8
sqlite_incdir = sqlite_libdir = None
sqlite_inc_paths = [ '/usr/include',
                     '/usr/include/sqlite',
                     '/usr/include/sqlite3',
                     '/usr/local/include',
                     '/usr/local/include/sqlite',
                     '/usr/local/include/sqlite3',
                   $SQLITE_INSTALL_LOCATION/include,
                 ]
...
```

Once you've changed the setup.py in your python source finish up compiling and installing python assuming the install location is $PYTHON_INSTALL_LOCATION

```
$ cd  Python-2.7.13
$ LD_RUN_PATH=$SQLITE_INSTALL_LOCATION/lib ./configure --prefix=$PYTHON_INSTALL_LOCATION --enable-shared --enable-unicode=ucs4
$ LD_RUN_PATH=$SQLITE_INSTALL_LOCATION/lib make 
$ LD_RUN_PATH=$SQLITE_INSTALL_LOCATION/lib make install
```

Once you do that you should have a Python version with SQLite3 support installed at $PYTHON_INSTALL_LOCATION/bin/python

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: I'm not a Mac User, but by common knowledge i give you
>   this info.

You could follow the next instructions:

### Use Homebrew

As this [page](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/rails/install-sqlite3/) mention: If you need to upgrade sqlite, you could use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Homebrew implies an aditional "software manager". So you should know how to use it before.

### Install it from the source

As this [page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm) metion:

1. Download the [sqlite-autoconf package](http://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-autoconf-3080803.tar.gz)
2. Compile it and install it:

:

```
$ tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3071502.tar.gz
$ cd sqlite-autoconf-3071502
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ make install
```

### Either Homebrew or Source, verfy it

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version_info
(2, 4, 1)
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version_info
(3, 6, 11)

>>> from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version_info
(2, 5, 5)
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version_info
(3, 6, 18)
```

Maybe you need to uninstall previous version of pysqlite. In any way, you should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546162/344501) to understand better the **sqlite/python** relationship.

Answer (score -1):

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

python get-pip.py

python [complete path]

python c:\folder\get-pip.py