# How to update python-sqlite on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, sqlite, foreign-keys

Python 2.7.3 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard (downloaded from python.org), tells me it is using sqlite 3.6.12 (`sqlite3.sqlite_version`).
However, to use foreign keys, I need at least sqlite 3.6.19.

How can I update sqlite alone?

I already tried `pip install pysqlite` (from this question/answer: [Updating the SQLite3 build on my python install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904629/updating-the-sqlite3-build-on-my-python-install)), but the sqlite_version did not change. `pip search sqlite` shows pysqlite 2.6.3 is installed, but I still have, both from commands `python` and `python2.7`

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version  #3.6.12
>>> sqlite3.version         #2.6.0 (yeah, no 2.6.3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first need to install [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), then build and install `pysqlite`, making sure that it's building against your newly installed version of sqlite and not the system's version of sqlite. Alternately, if pysqlite is dynamically linked, you might be able to fiddle with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make your existing pysqlite load the newer version of the library.

For more, see: https://groups.google.com/group/python-sqlite/browse_thread/thread/9fb6694c803431eb

Comment: Thanks, I see that there's no other way than that. It's actually much simpler to manually enforce the foreign keys by code, so I guess that's what I'll do.

Comment: Via your Google Groups link I found http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite , which recommends against Macs doing a static build ("Users of Mac OS X please take care; the Apple-supplied SQLite contains additional code to support..."). But install-source.txt mentions nowhere the standard sqlite3 module, just pysqlite2. Ick! Question: How do I use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH trick?

Comment: "making sure that it's building against your newly installed version of sqlite and not the system's version of sqlite" this is exactly what I need to do (I have sqlite from homebrew I want to link against), can you please explain how to or point to some docs?