# How do I upgrade the SQLite version used by Python's SQLite3 module on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, sqlite

I would like to use the SQLite version 3.8 with Python, but the SQLite3 module is using an out of date version. I've installed SQLite version 3.8.4.3 on my Mac, but sqlite3.sqlite_version still returns 3.7.13.

I've done quite a bit of searching on SO and elsewhere, but can't seem to find a definitive answer.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you install SQLite 3.8.4.3? Binary installer from sqlite.org, Homebrew, check out and build the source, …?

Comment: I believe I tried all of those. Will one make sure the new version is used by the python package?

Comment: No, none of them will make sure without doing something additional. But nobody can tell you how to proceed further without knowing _which_ one you did. (And where the libs ended up, and what your `PATH` looks like, and so forth.)

Comment: One more thing: after installing `pysqlite`, I don't think it replaces the `sqlite3` module; I think it gives you a new module with a different name, something like `pysqlite2.dbapi`. So you need to import *that* (or `import <that> as sqlite3`) and check *its* `sqlite3_version`; the one in the stdlib isn't going to change.

Comment: I've been using both the pysqlite and sqlite3 modules and checking the version as you indicated.
`which -a sqlite3`
returns
`/usr/bin/sqlite3
/usr/local/bin/sqlite3` and `echo $PATH` returns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin`. Are these what you need to further advise?

Comment: OK, I think that's enough. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your comments, your problem is that your pre-installed sqlite 3.7 comes higher on your path than your third-party 3.8. This means that when you build `pysqlite2`, by default, it will find and use that 3.7, so it's not doing you any good. And you probably don't want to change around your whole path just to deal with this.

But that's fine, as long as the 3.8 is found first at build time, it doesn't matter what comes first at runtime; the path to 3.8 will be baked into the module. There are a number of ways to do this, but the simplest is something like this:

```
$ brew install sqlite3
$ sudo -s
# LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include pip2.7 install pysqlite
# ^D
$ python
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.13'
>>> import pysqlite2.dbapi2
>>> pysqlite2.dbapi2.sqlite_version
'3.8.6'
```

The `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` variables came from the output of the `brew install sqlite3` step. If you've installed `sqlite3` in some other way, you'll need to get the appropriate values—possibly `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`, but if not, search for `libsqlite3.dylib` and `sqlite3.h`.

Note that if you follow *exactly* these steps, you'll get a non-fat version of `libsqlite3`, meaning that `pysqlite2` won't work in 32-bit mode. I doubt that's an issue for you, but if it is, you can just install it `--universal`, or use a different installer instead of Homebrew.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to update your Python to the latest version because sqlite3 is shipped with Python.

Otherwise have to update the [pysqlite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite) package as well. Under Linux there is a precompiled package python-sqlite.

You can do that by using easy_install. For building this package you need some packages. Nessecerily build pysqlite with the new installed version of [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), in your case 3.8.4.3.

```
sudo easy_install pysqlite
```

or

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pysqlite
```

Comment: I've tried that, but no luck. Do I need to do something to ensure that the new install of the pysqlite package is built using the new sqlite3 version?

Comment: You have to be sure that your simple sqlite command reffers the new one. In the building output there may is a hint which version was used. I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984403/how-to-update-python-sqlite-on-mac-osx).

Comment: `easy_install` (a) is obsolete, and (b) requires `setuptools` just as much as `pip` does (in fact, it's part of `setuptools`), so you really shouldn't be recommending it.

Comment: easy_install requires setuptools, I changed that. I looked on a Mac and just found easy_install but not pip. So I wrote easy_install  for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @wenzul - Can you provide more detail on how to make sure the build and install refers to the new version? I saw that link, but couldn't follow the needed steps.

Comment: is there a similar solution for Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, just use: python3 -m pip install -U pysqlite3

Answer (score 2):

If you use Anaconda as your package manager, run `conda install -c anaconda sqlite`.

Run `python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"` to confirm that you have the latest version.

[Source](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/sqlite)

Comment: This isn't really a great answer to the original question as they don't mention Anaconda so they probably aren't using it. As general advice though, if you want to play with newer versions of packages in the system Python installation then it's a great idea to use a package manager.

Comment: According to [Anaconda's Sqlite page](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/sqlite), the current version is 3.29. They suggest the same `conda install ...` line you do, but when I run it, I still end up with 3.23.1 (the version I had previously). To force it to install the latest version (should you need that), I called `conda install sqlite=[version_number]`. Of course, now I'm waiting for Anaconda to try to resolve dependency conflicts...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Windows.

1. Download the latest pre-compiled binary files for Sqlite3
   https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
2. Find the DLL library sqlite3.dll
3. Find the Python library folder, where Python sqlite3.dll is stored
4. Backup Python sqlite3.dll and replace it with the latest sqlite3.dll

Comment: This answer is meant for Windows systems, while OP asked for MacOS

Comment: True but it's the only thing I've found on this subject

Comment: it is not working as the main source for sqlite3 exists under Lib/sqlite3