# Upgraded python 3.6 to 3.9 but sqlite3 version is still 3.22 instead of 3.35

Tags: python, sqlite

There are a lot of questions around this topic but I couldn't find an answer for this question. I have python 3.6.9 where `sqlite3.sqlite_version` is 3.22. I need to use the window functions which are available starting 3.25. I upgraded to python3.9 which is supposed to use sqlite 3.35 but when I run `sqlite2.sqlite_version` I still see 3.22.

I'm trying to do this on a linux server. I have a local python3.9 installation on a mac using anaconda and that has the correct sqlite version i.e. 3.25.

Am I missing something after upgrading to python3.9?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade the SQLite version used by Python's SQLite3 module on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345972/how-do-i-upgrade-the-sqlite-version-used-by-pythons-sqlite3-module-on-mac)

Comment: I'm trying get python3.9 use sqlite 3.35 on a linux server. My local mac machine is fine and is using 3.35. This answer certainly is helpful, but not sure if directly applies to linux. I need to look into what `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` are from the answer. I was hoping there would be an easier way to do this but it does not look like it.

Comment: For python modules, you can see which file it's referencing by using the `__file__` attribute. What does `sqlite3.__file__` give you for both?

Comment: It gives the respective files for both. `/usr/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/__init__.py` and `/usr/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py`