# How to create a table in SQLite using python without rowid?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, rowid

I would like to create an SQLite table in python without the default rowid field.

For example, I have tried

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "CREATE TABLE tblTest (myid VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, testField1 VARCHAR(14), testField2 VARCHAR(2500) ) WITHOUT ROWID "

cursor.execute(sql)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WITHOUT": syntax error
```

Any suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need a newer version of SQLite. The `without rowid` syntax requires 3.8.2 or later.

[Reference](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html)

The version of the sqlite library that's linked to the sqlite3 executable . . .

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41 c7c6050ef060877ebe77b41d959e9df13f8c9b5e
```

The version that's incorporated into python's standard library . . .

```
$ python
[snip]
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.9'
```

For information about how version checking can mislead you, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546162/562459).

Comment: `version` [is not the version of the SQLite library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.version).