# more recent version of sqlite on openshift python-3.3 cartridge?

Tags: python, sqlite, openshift

Is there any way so I can use a more recent version of sqlite in my application in a python-3.3 cartridge?

Currently openshift python-3.3 cartridges are using sqlite 3.6.20 which is more than 5 years old.

I tried to make sqlite from source and by adding it to path make python use the newer version of sqlite, but it didn't work.

I also found [this answer on openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546162/919944), had some good info, but the solution doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the new sqlite version in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR and refer to it specifically in that location instead of trying to add it to your path.

Comment: thanks for your response, I've put the the new sqlite version in $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, how can I refer to it? or where should I do the referring?