# insert + upsert works in sqlite3 console, but on python it shows syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert, upsert

I'm using sqlite version 3.25.1.
When I execute the following query in sqlite console, it works:

```
insert into cases (bi, age, shape, margin, density, severity) 
values (5, 67, 3, 5, 3, 1)
on conflict(bi, age, shape, margin, density, severity) 
DO UPDATE SET frequency=frequency+1;
```

But when I execute it on python, it says:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "on": syntax error

Here is my code on python:

```
C.execute('insert into cases (bi, age, shape, margin, density, severity) '
          'values (5, 67, 3, 5, 3, 1)'
          'on conflict(bi, age, shape, margin, density, severity) '
          'DO UPDATE SET frequency=frequency+1', ())
```

I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Try a space inside the quotes at the end of your second line.

Comment: @thesilkworm, I tried it and it still show that syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible `UPSERT` is not included in the sqlite3 version that python loads. From the [sqlite3 doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

> UPSERT syntax was added to SQLite with version 3.24.0 (2018-06-04).

To find the sqlite version in python:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

Comment: Yes you're right. the version is 3.20.1. How can I upgrade it?

Comment: That, I'm afraid, is out of my ken. [This old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545479/force-python-to-forego-native-sqlite3-and-use-the-installed-latest-sqlite3-ver) may be a good starting point.