# upgrade sqlite to 3.24+ pycharm

Tags: python, sqlite, pycharm, upsert

I'm using pycharm for the current project.

When using the sqlite console under pycharm it shows that it has the version 3.25.1, which means that the sqlite upsert works perfectly. But on python, when I do `import sqlite3` it imports the version 3.20.1 of it.

I don't know why that difference in versions and I want to import the latest version of sqlite in python to be able to work with upserts.

Edit: I'm using Fedora 27 and python 3.7.0

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show **OS Version**, **Python Version** both in PyCharm and Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that sqlite 3.24+ requires Fedora 29+.
I just upgraded my fedora to version 29 and I got sqlite 3.24.0

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the version of packages when selecting in pycharm Settings > Project Interepter > and upgrade the packages you want, here's a link to an old question, however, there are some recent answers, hope it what you want [Link to an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545479/force-python-to-forego-native-sqlite3-and-use-the-installed-latest-sqlite3-ver)

Comment: I don't see SQLite in the list :(