# Pysqlcipher3 cannot find sqllite3 shared library

Tags: python, shared-libraries, embedded-linux, yocto

I have custom linux OS for an ARM board.
I compiled the pysqlcipher3 for the platform in the yocto build. The python3 program fails to identify a sqlite3 symbol in the shared libraries.

```
>>> from pysqlcipher3 import dbapi2 as sqlcipher
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysqlcipher3/dbapi2.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pysqlcipher3._sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysqlcipher3/_sqlite3.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension
```

But I have added sqlite3 packages in the yocto. I identified the library in the rootfs.

/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0

I have checked the symbols in the library using the nm command and it seems to have the missing symbol  (sqlite3_enable_load_extension).
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Some forum suggested the usage of LD_PRELOAD option, It mess ups with sqlcipher operations

when I try to opne the database I get this error

```
getSingle failed  file is encrypted or is not a database
```

Comment: pysqlcipher3 needs libsqlcipher to be installed, did you add it as well? I don't know the state but you can find a recipe [here](https://github.com/openwebos/meta-webos/blob/master/recipes-upstreamable/sqlcipher/sqlcipher.bb). Did you create a pysqlcipher3 recipe or you just compiled it with Yocto sdk ?

Comment: Yes I have added sqlcipher to the build and I compiled with yocto sdk.

Comment: sqlite3_enable_load_extension was removed, see [debian tracker](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=478337). Can you check following command `objdump -T /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0|grep -c sqlite3_enable_load_extension`?

Comment: Did you see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546162/6225741)? Maybe we have to remove SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION option from sqlite3.

Comment: objdump show that symbol exists. I will check the other link

Comment: It got by building the sqlcipher package with --enable-load-extension flag. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: How did you manage to get pysqlcipher3 installed in your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pysqlcipher module depends on the libsqlcipher.so library in the device. The libsqlcipher should be built with --enable-load-extension to avoid this error

For Yocto build, I have added the flag in sqlcipher recipe file to avoid the issue.

```
EXTRA_OECONF = "--enable-load-extension --disable-tcl  CFLAGS=-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC"
```